# Not finding attached property Dock of DockPanel

Tags: silverlight

Here's my code...we can find a button tag in this code. There for button tag i want to use attached property Dock of DockPanel. But i am not getting it in the intellisence. How can i get that.

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"
xmlns:mswindows="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

<toolkit:DockPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button Content="Create New Employee" Height="27" Width="136"></Button>
    <sdk:DataGrid Background="White">

    </sdk:DataGrid>

</toolkit:DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attached property lives in the same namaspace as the `DockPanel` so you need to use `toolkit:DockPanel.Dock`:

```
<toolkit:DockPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button toolkit:DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Create New Employee" />    
</toolkit:DockPanel>
```

Here is a good [tutorial how to use the DockPanel in Silverlight](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/justinangel/archive/2008/10/30/silverlight-toolkit-dockpanel.aspx).

Comment: Yeah right..But thing is here i could not find toolkit:DockPanel.Dock in the intellisense..

Comment: @bantu Intellisense sometimes gets confused, just type it in and in theory it should work. If not updated your question with the error message.

Comment: It worked out. For sometime it showed it as error. Thank you for tutorial link also, its useful.